# Curl_easy_cleanup doesn't free resources

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, free, libcurl

I'm made a multi-threaded HTTP Proxy using `libcurl`, the problem is that the RAM used by my application increases by time (after responding to an http request)

I'm sure that I free all the variables allocated dynamically, and headers list used by `libcurl`, also I run `curl_easy_cleanup` after every request. but after debugging my application I found that `curl_easy_cleanup` doesn't free anything not even a byte (after removing it, the application uses the same amount of memory)

The used memory increases quickly at the beginning then it become to increase slowly (and sometimes doesn't increase at all)

The only moment when the application frees a significant amount of memory is when I close the browser (but not to the first amount used when the application is lunched).

Valgrind doesn't signal definitely memory leaks (some possible memory leaks, but just few bytes), it's like `free`, `curl_easy_cleanup` `curl_global_cleanup` doesn't have any affect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are viewing the total amount of memory used by the application. This very rarely goes down, and only when very large amounts of memory is freed in one go.

This is because the heap that the application uses will not in itself be freed, only the small blocks that go into the heap, which will be reused by `new` or `malloc` next time you need a block of that size.

In other words, what you are seeing is the "high watermark" of the applications memory usage go up for a while, until it settles at some level. Which is why valgrind doesn't detect anything - you are not actually "leaking", you are just growing the heap until it can accomodate all the allocations you make during a run of your program.

You can try this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int *mem[10000];
   string dummy;
   for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
   {
      mem[i] = new int [256];  // 1KB of memory. 
   }
   cout << "Hit enter to continue..." << endl;
   cin >> dummy;
   for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
   {
      delete [] mem[i];
   }
   cout << "Hit enter to exit..." << endl;
   cin >> dummy;
```

}

You will see that the application grows to 10MB or so, then deletes everything, but it will remain at the same size.

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about the total amount of memory used by the application displayed in Ubuntu system monitor. I'm willing to port my application to a router with 16/32MB, it means that everything is OK ?

Comment: Depends on how much memory you actually use in your Ubuntu system - if you are getting to several megabytes, then maybe not. But I doubt it's a memory leak as such.

Comment: For e.g when I respond on the first request, it goes to 5mb (initially: 780kb) when I close the browser it goes down to 3mb, but if i continue to send requests it will not increase a lot (to 6mb for e.g) then it doesn't increase at all for a while. but when i close the browser it decreases but not lot

Comment: Right, so clearly a proxy will have to "hold" some information, which explains why it goes up and down with connection and disconnection. Like I said, you will have a "high watermark". And bear in mind that what often happens is that different size objects are allocated and freed in different order, so there will be "holes" in the heap. The runtime library will only really free a block of heap if it's completely empty - so you can have an allocation of 1 byte causing a block of a couple of megabytes from not being freed until that 1 bytes is freed.